# WiFi isn't able to turn on

Tags: networking, wireless

I've been looking on the internet for a long time to fix my problem and usually people just do `rfkill ublock all` but it doesn't work. When I go to my WiFi menu in settings it lets me turn it on but as soon as I click that it turns off again.

Also, when I go to turn off airplane mode, it says "Use hardware switch to turn off".

Comment: also when i do rfkill list all is says
ideapad_wlan LAN
       soft blocked: no
       hard blocked: yes
phy0: wireless LAN
      soft blocked: no
      hard blocked: yes

Comment: Find the physical switch, and turn it on. If there is none, check the BIOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a physical switch or button on your computer that needs to be toggled.  Sometimes this is a slide switch or separate button, other times an F-key does this depending on whether the Fn key is held or not.

Comment: this didn't work, or atleast with the F-keys, i tried all of them witha and without Fn, and i can't find an actual physical button on my computer, my computer is a lenevo b575

Comment: On your device, it should be F7 or Fn+F7.  Also check to make sure it is enabled in the BIOS.  See https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht071417, and https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht072689 mentions that there may be a physical switch.

Comment: Another search indicates it could be F5/Fn+F5.